# How does any application (chrome, flash, etc) get a time resolution better than the system time resolution?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome, timer

This article on Microsoft's tech net site supplies an `exe` that will calculate your windows machine's minimum time resolution - this should be the smallest "tick" available to any application on that machine:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897568.aspx

The result of running this app on my current box is 15.625 ms.  I have also run tests against Internet Explorer and gotten the exact same resolution from the Date() javascript function.

What is confusing is that the SAME test I ran against IE gives back much finer resolution for Google's Chrome browser (resolution of 1ms) and for a flash movie running in IE (1ms).  Can anyone explain how any application can get a clock resolution better then the machine's clock?  If so, is there some way I can get a consistently better resolution in browsers other then Chrome (without using flash)?

The first answer below leads to two other questions:

1. How does a multi-media timer get
   times between system clock ticks.  I
   imagine the system clock as an
   analog watch with a ticking hand,
   each tick being 15ms.  How are times
   between ticks measured?
2. Are multimedia timers available to
   browsers, especially Internet
   Explorer?  Can I access one with C#
   or Javascript without having to push
   software to a user's
   browser/machine?

Comment: They're available to every application that uses them. Read the docs.

Comment: David - if there is a Javascript timer with resolution better then Date(), it's not clear (as you suggest) what it is, hence the question

Answer (score 4):

You can get down to 1 ms with [multimedia timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712704(VS.85).aspx) and even further with QueryPerformanceCounter.

See also [GetLocalTime() API time resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668/getlocaltime-api-time-resolution#49720).

EDIT: Partial answer to the new subquestion ...

System time resolution was around 15 ms on the Windows 3 and 95 architecture. On NT (and successors) you can get better resolution from the hardware abstraction layer (HAL). The [QueryPerformanceCounter counts elapsed time, not CPU cycles](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/08/8931563.aspx) article, written by the Raymond Chen, may give you some additional insights.

As for the browsers - I have no idea what they are using for timers and how they interact with the OS.

Comment: Interesting.  This leads to to additional queestions:

Comment: Unfortunately pre-vista the setting is global (eg. all timers in the system become higher res which can cause problems); It also does really bad things to power usage (although i don't know to what extent that is OS dependent)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the timeBeginPeriod API. From MSDN: "This function affects a global Windows setting. Windows uses the lowest value (that is, highest resolution) requested by any process."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713413(VS.85).aspx

(Markdown didn't like parens in the URL)

See "Inside Windows NT High Resolution Timers" referenced from the link you posted.

Comment: In URLs, you can safely replace the opening parens with %28 and the closing one with %29. This works around the markdown annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

The [APIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_APIC_Architecture) on the processor runs at bus speed and has a timer.  They may be using that instead of the system time.  (Or they might just be giving a bunch of precision that isn't there.)

This [description of the Local APIC](http://osdev.berlios.de/pic.html) mentions using it as a timer.

(It may also be the case that there is some performance counter they are using. That actually seems more likely since a device driver would be needed to program the APIC.)