# Should GetLocalTime() 'skip backwards'?

Tags: c++, windows

I am aware that `QueryPerformanceCounter` can return values that are non-monotonic/discontinuous (ie. time can appear to jump backwards) due to sampling the time from unsynchronised clocks spread across multi-core or multi-processor architectures.

I would have thought that `GetLocalTime()` avoided these issues, although I cannot find anything definitive to say so. When I created this function:

```
int GetTimeAsMillisecondsSinceMidnight()
{
    SYSTEMTIME theTime;
    GetLocalTime( &theTime );
    return 3600000*theTime.wHour + 60000*theTime.wMinute
        + 1000*theTime.wSecond + theTime.wMilliseconds;
}
```

... I was surprised to generate events at rates of 20-30 per second, time stamp them using the return value from this function, and discover that sometimes the timestamp "jumped backwards" by as much as 4 seconds on a reasonably up-to-date Windows 8 64-bit system running on a Core i7 processor.

What is the likely cause of this "jumping backwards" in time? If `GetLocalTime()` is the culprit, are there any alternatives that would have a similar resolution/accuracy, but avoid the issues with time discontinuities?

Comment: Is your test program using threads at all?

Comment: Semi-related: have you got a link for your first sentence; how did you become aware of it?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668/getlocaltime-api-time-resolution) has some good information on time functions, and includes an answer which mentions the issue with QueryPerformanceCounter. I had known about that issue for maybe 3-4 years - not sure where I first came across it.

Comment: @GregHewgill - the calling program makes extensive use of threads, but there is only ever one thread that gets and writes a timestamp using this function. I have not had time to extract this function into a test program with only a single thread.

Comment: I don't suppose you could do something crazy like query every core for its time, at roughly the same time, and store the differences between them, and from then on use a helper method that would use the difference you originally found to correct the time you requested for? For example, if you queried 8 cores and 1 of them was off by a minute, then that minute could be subtracted out of future calls to keep it in line with the rest of the cores.

Comment: If I found that one core was off by a minute, I'd take the PC back and ask for a refund! I was shocked to find even a 4 second disparity... but it could be that some of my occasionally extremely processor-intensive code is holding up one core by that long, and then that logjam causes the O/S to reallocate threads to cores, and the result is that the (low intensity) thread that is timestamping things ends up on a core that was previously unable to update its clock due to high processor load. But this (I believe) should resynchronise (jump forward) at some point. That's my best guess.

Comment: I'd be surprised if each core was keeping time. AFAIK, that's not a CPU function (although a SoC may have a single shared RTC).

Comment: It's perfectly normal for the clock to jump either way a few seconds.  That just means that it was running a bit slow or a bit fast, and Windows has synchronized it with an external source.